# Auto Layout left margin constraint based on percentage of screen width

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I have 4 buttons. I want them to be 13% of the screen width from the left edge and bottom edge. I'm using Auto Layout and Size Classes. I know I can specify a number of points in Interface Builder with Storyboards but obviously this won't get the job done when going from device to device. Do I need to hook up a constraint through an IBOutlet and calculate the constraint there in code to achieve the desired result? Or is this possible using Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

This is special case, which can't be handled in IB (AFAIK). These combo boxes don't contain all available attributes.

Do it in code:

```
let con = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal,
  toItem: fullWidthView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.13, constant: 0.0)
```

Replace `myView` with your button. Replace `fullWidthView` with any view which occupies whole width of the device. Typically `UIViewController.view`.

And do the same thing with `.Bottom`, `.Height` and `fullHeightView`.

Comment: This will crash if not all constraints are set properly, correct?

Comment: I get this: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Invalid pairing of layout attributes'
*** First throw call stack: